# Geth gives empty answer for ANY chain data query

Tags: ethereum, geth

I'm running geth on an extra machine in my office.  It is all synced and should be a full node.  However, when I attach to the console and issue queries, the rely is always "0".
Can't get balance of any accounts or any contract info.

However I have peers, the synced blocks are up to date, etc.  No errors reported.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full geth returns empty response when it's not synced. It can take up hours / days depending of the power of your computer to be fully synced.

If you want to quickly access data without syncing the chain you can use a light geth.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  Thanks!